# Getting bad substitution error in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a variable **COUNTRY**="INDIA"

and another sets of variables:-
**INDIA_POPULATION**="5,00,00,000", **CHINA_POPULATION**="6,00,00,000".

In script I am trying to call them using command:-

echo ${ ${COUNTRY}_POPULATION }

But I am getting bad substitution[image] error. Can someone please tell how to solve it ??

Comment: You can't nest parameter expansions in bash.  Perhaps in your case, it would make more sense to use an associative array `POPULATION`, which has the keys _INDIA_ and _CHINA_.

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misplaced a bracket: `{$COUNTRY}_POPULATION` should be `${COUNTRY}_POPULATION`. But even then it would not work as you expect. Use bash *indirect expansion*:

```bash
$ name="${COUNTRY}_POPULATION"
$ echo "${!name}"
5,00,00,000
```

Or, if you have bash version >= 4.3, you can also use a *nameref*:

```bash
$ declare -n name="${COUNTRY}_POPULATION"
$ echo "$name"
5,00,00,000
```